# Stop Recycleing or Rebinding RecyclerView top header Items

Tags: android, binding, android-recyclerview

I don't want to rebind my top header view items because its contains some graph chart that recalculation not time efficient. Suppose my recycleView is:

```
ItemTypeHead1
ItemTypeHead2
ItemTypeList
ItemTypeList
.
.
ItemTypeList
```

Normally for doing this I take some boolean value for each of header and in onBindViewHolder check that boolean value. Ex:

```
if (!isItemTypeHead1Created && holder instanceof ItemTypeHead1) {
        ((ItemTypeHead1) holder).onBindDataUpdate(Data mData);
        isItemTypeHead1Created = true;
    }
```

So, It don't bind again. But I am looking for any better solution. 
Please share your idea and let's discuss on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(ItemTypeHead1, 0);
```

This method  don't recyle anyview of type `ItemTypeHead1` (max number cache = 0)

You can read this for more detail:
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2oks1l/recyclerviewgetrecycledviewpoolsetmaxrecycledviews/

Comment: Thats good. But in sometime I need to update ItemTypeHead1 data when user change ItemTypeList data. Then how I do this? @RoShan

Comment: I think when you use `notifyItemChanged`  or `notifyDataSetChanged`, it will force reload the view.